# What is "dimension" in Wolfram's Physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, hausdorff-measure

In [The Notion of Dimension](https://www.wolframphysics.org/technical-introduction/limiting-behavior-and-emergent-geometry/the-notion-of-dimension/), which is section 4.5 in Wolfram's Physics Project, they describe a kind process for estimating "dimension".

Suppose I have a metric space $(X, \epsilon)$ for which I am free to induce opens balls up to radius $r$. Suppose $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a measure space on the same set $X$. I can parametrize our measure by the radius, which in the linked article considers asymptotically  $\mu_r \sim \mathcal{O}(r^d)$ where $d \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a kind of dimension. In my personal notes I have been calling this "scale dimension", but I am now looking to connect my thinking with the literature.

The informal notion of ["Haussdorf dimension"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HausdorffDimension.html) given on Wolfram MathWorld looks *highly similar*. It is given in the form $d = \frac{\ln N}{\ln s}$ where $N$ and $s$ are some parameters. But more generally it seems to be defined in terms of Hausdorff measure (according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension)). I may be confused about the definition of Hausdorff measure here, but my thinking is that (hyper)graphs are countable so they would always have Hausdorff measure of zero for any $r$. Thus the Hausdorff dimension of a graph would be zero, which is not what we are describing above with "scale dimension".

[Minkowski-Bouligand dimension](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Minkowski-BouligandDimension.html) seems to consider arbitrarily small radii in defining dimension. With these graphs our radius can be chosen as a count representing path lengths, in which case an "arbitrarily small $r$" doesn't make a lot sense.

So this notion of dimension being used here on graph/hypergraphs seems similar to Hausdorff dimension, but in a countable setting.

What is the notion of dimension being used in Wolfram's Physics project?

Comment: The Hausdorff dimension of a graph is, I'm almost certain, going to be "$0$" or "$1$" most of the time.

Comment: $d=\frac{\ln N}{\ln s}$ is a heuristic, certainly not a definition of Hausdorff dimension ("not all fractals are self-similar"). The Hausdorff dimension is the unique (extended) real number marking the boundary between the Hausdorff measure being constantly $\infty$ or constantly $0$. It coincides with Lebesgue measure for $d=0,1,2,\cdots$.

Comment: *If* $\mu$ is a true Hausdorff measure, then it is indeed true that $\mu(rA)=r^d\mu(A)$ for a measurable $A$ and $d$ the dimension, $rA$ seen as a scaling (in the Euclidean, and probably in any real, vector space). This may align with "$\mu_r\sim\mathcal{O}(r^d)$" but I'm not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for the clarifying point. I just meant the measure scales [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of the radius to the power of dimension. I had not considered the [homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) property you just showed.

Comment: Big-O is not proportional to, when used correctly, so a measure the scales Big-O to the power of the dimension is generally behaving quite differently to a true Hausdorff measure.

Answer (score 3):

There's not much more to this than what the writer is telling you plainly: in some particular unstated example the quantity $\mu_r$ is asymptotic to $r^d$, and in the writer's personal notes the number $d$ is called "scale dimension". You can happily convince yourself that the Euclidean plane has scale dimension equal to $2$, and in general Euclidean $n$-space has scale dimension equal to $n$. And if you know any hyperbolic geometry you can convince yourself that $\mu_r$ is asymptotic to $e^r$ and hence scale dimension is undefined (or is infinite, depending on your taste).

Your account of Hausdorff dimension leaves out ***all*** of the subtleties of its full definition, regarding limits of various parameters as other parameters approach $0$ and/or $\infty$. So you should be rather skeptical of any surface similarities with "scale dimension" that you might perceive, until you have a very solid understanding of the full definition of Hausdorff dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> So this notion of dimension being used here on graph/hypergraphs seems similar to Hausdorff dimension, but in a countable setting.
>
> What is the notion of dimension being used in Wolfram's Physics project?

Probably Wolfram could give you a better answer, but if you
read the section carefully, it is a **heuristic** attempt at
a **non-rigorous** notion of dimension that is based roughly
on $\sim \mathcal{O}(r^d)$ behavior. It agrees with other definitions of dimension for graphs which are modeled on Euclidean spaces. It is certainly **not** meant to be a
formal definition of dimension such as those defined in
mathematics. This is physics after all.

Also, the Hausdorff dimension you refer to is only defined
in the context of a metric space. There is no metric space in
the Wolfram Physics Project models.